# Computability of function composition

Tags: computability, church-turing-thesis

I have some problems to understand computability and hope you can help me.
In the lecture we had following problem:

Consider the three partial functions $f,g,h\colon N \to N$, where $f$ is computable and $g$ is not computable. The following two statements are correct:

1. If $h(x) = g(f(x))$, then $h$ could be computable.
2. If $g(x) = h(f(x))$, then $h$ is not computable.

Well, 2 is clear I think, because we know that $g$ is not computable and $f$ is computable, so $h$ has to be not computable, otherwise $g$ would be computable.

But 1 is a big problem for me. If $f$ is computable and $g$ is not computable, how can $h$ be computable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $f(x) = 0$. Then $g(f(x))$ is computable for any function $g$, computable or not. This explains 1.

As for 2, the composition of two computable functions is computable, so if both $f$ and $h$ are computable, so is $g$. Since $f$ is computable and $g$ isn't, the only conclusion is that $h$ is not computable.

Comment: So what the professor said is wrong? (2) h has to be computable. mmh

Comment: Sorry, I got the notation wrong.

Comment: No problem :=)
But i don't understand 1.  if $f(x)=0$ then we get $g(0)$. How can this be computable if $g$ by definition isn't?

Comment: If $f(x) = 0$ for all $x$, then $g(f(x)) = g(0)$ for all $x$. Now $g(0)$ is just some natural number, say 555. Are you claiming that the function $h(x) = 555$ isn't computable?